# Varying the values of variables while keeping their sum constant

Tags: python, variables

I am wanting to vary three (or more) variables in Python, all between 0 and 1, while keeping the sum of (the squares of) them constant.

They are the probability densities of a quantum superposition state.

So the statement:

```
alpha**2 + beta**2 + gamma**2 = 1
```

is some kind of constraint.

Is there any way to do this please?

Comment: Firstly, two things: 1) The exponent operator in Python is `**`. `^` is bitwise XOR. 2) `1**2 == 1` and `0**2 == 0`. **Edit** Oh, you mean [0, 1] ∈ *reals*. I thought you meant [0, 1] ∈ *integers*.

Comment: Sounds more like a [mathematics.se] problem.